# prgram to check number of days between starting and ending year

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to write a program where I need the user to input a starting year and ending year and then the program calculates the number of days between the years. I have tried to attempt this and am a little stuck. I am required to also work out if the time includes leap years aswell.
if anyone is able to help me out would be appreciated.

- The output should be as follows :

Year 1 :1980

Year 2: 2022

Number of days : 15706

```
import datetime
firstDate = input("Year 1?")
secondDate = input("Year 2?")
firstDateObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(firstDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
secondDateObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(secondDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
totalDays = (firstDateObj – secondDateObj).days
print(totalDays, "Day(s)")
except ValueError as e:
print(e)
```

thanks

Comment: Why does your`strptime` format contain %m and %d if you don't want month and day?

Comment: hi Mark, i need to calculate the years that have leap years in them so I thought by adding months and days as well to the sum it would help in that sense.

Comment: Yes, knowing the month and day would be essential for getting an exact count of leap days.  But your input doesn't ask for dates, it only asks for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the datetime.date method:

Using this method you can just take the first of January of each year:

```
from datetime import date
first_year = input("Year 1? ")
second_year = input("Year 2? ")
first_date = date(int(first_year), 1, 1)
second_date = date(int(second_year), 1, 1)
```

Subtracting these elements returns a [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object -

```
between_days = second_date - first_date
print(between_days.days)
```